# GWT/Maven Project - Maven dependency order wrong

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, dependencies

I use the HtmlUnit (Particular the WebClient class) library in my GWT/Maven App. But for some reason there seems to be a very old version in the GWT Jar, which is used. Under "Java Build Path" in the "Order and Export" Tab, i moved my "Maven Dependencies" to the top. So it should look for the sources here first, right?

Why is then always the old version from the GWT Jar used? How can I prevent that?

It the pom.xml it only is shown once:
[image]

The two classes:
[image]

Comment: GWT is notorious for embedding ancient versions of dependencies into its monster jar (at one point its Servlet version was a decade out of date); modularizing the GWT build has been a "high priority" item for about four years now.

Comment: GWT 2.6.0-rc1 uses HtmlUnit 2.13, you might look into using that. Worst case, you find a bug, and the final release of 2.6 is that much better.

Answer (score 0):

GWT uses HtmlUnit for `GWTTestCase`s, and will only be modularized (with declared/managed dependencies) in GWT 3.0 scheduled for Google I/O 2014.

Maven does not support arbitrary classpaths (only compile, test and runtime), so you have no other choice than moving your use of HtmlUnit into another Maven module that wouldn't depend on GWT.

Note that even if GWT were using managed dependencies, it wouldn't solve your problem: `GWTTestCase` would then break, because the versionyou use (HtmlUnit 2.13) is not backwards compatible with the on bundled in GWT 2.5.1 (HtmlUnit 2.9).
…or as Colin suggested, try GWT 2.6.0-rc1 which uses (bundles) HtmlUnit 2.13.